# least square estimator of regression x onto y

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, estimators

I've been reading linear regression and least square estimator. Suppose we have i.i.d data $(x_1, y_q), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_n,y_n)$ such that we use a linear regression model $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$ and learnt the fact that we often derive least square estimator $\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_iy_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i^2}$.

However I wonder what would be the effect if we do regression of x onto y. Would we then be able to use the least square estimate for the regression of x onto y to estimate of $\frac{1}{\beta}$?

How do we decide whether this is a good estimate in the first place?

Comment: Are you deliberately missing a constant term in your regression?  Or are the means zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prove that the reverse regression is not a good estimator for $1/\beta$, recall that OLS is generally [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares) (when regressing $y$ on $x$) for $cov(x,y)/var(x)$. Correspondingly, it is consistent for $cov(x,y)/var(y)$ when regressing $x$ on $y$.

When the relationship between error and regressor is (essentially, predeterminedness) is such that $\beta=cov(x,y)/var(x)$, to have that $cov(x,y)/var(y)=1/\beta$ would require that
$$
cov(x,y)/var(y)=var(x)/cov(x,y),
$$
and there is no reason to expect this to hold in general.

In fact, the condition could be reexpressed as
$$
\frac{cov(x,y)^2}{var(y)var(x)}=1,
$$
which is the limiting case of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), which is known to only obtain if the random variables in question are multiples of each other.

In that case, we have, say, $y=\beta x$, so that
$$
\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(x)}=\beta \cdot var(x)/var(x)=\beta 
$$
and
$$
\frac{cov(x,y)}{var(y)}=\frac{\beta \cdot var(x)}{\beta ^2var(x)}=\frac{1}{\beta }
$$

Here is a little graphical illustration (where you'd want to read the cases of regressing $x$ on $y$ rotating the plot counterclockwise by 90 degrees):

```
library(mvtnorm)
n <- 10000
cov.xy <- 0.5
var.y <- 1
var.x <- 4
beta <- cov.xy/var.x
dat <- rmvnorm(n, mean = rep(0,2), sigma = matrix(c(var.y, cov.xy, cov.xy, var.x), ncol=2))

y <- dat[,1]
x <- dat[,2]

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x, y, pch=19, cex=0.2, col="lightgreen")
abline(lm(y~x),lwd=2, col="lightgreen")          # a regression of y on x
abline(a=0, b=beta, lwd=2, col="green")          # what OLS of y on x is consistent for

plot(y, x, pch=19, cex=0.2, col="lightblue")
abline(lm(x~y), lwd=2, col="lightblue")          # a regression of x on y
abline(a=0, cov.xy/var.y, lwd=2, col="darkblue") # what OLS of x on y is consistent for
abline(a=0, b=1/beta, lwd=2, col="red")          # what OLS of x on y is NOT consistent for
```

[image]

Comment: how does the fact that OLS is consistent with regressing x onto y has to do with it is not a good estimate?

Comment: Consistency is a reasonably well-accepted (frequentist) criterion for a good estimator. And my post attempts to demonstrate that the coefficient of a regression of $x$ and $y$ will generally not be consistent for $1/\beta$ if the coefficient of a regression of $y$ on $x$ is consistent for $\beta$.

Answer (score 5):

No, in general you will obtain a different line wih ordinary least squares if you interchange *x* and *y*. You can easily check this with your formula by interchanging *x* and *y* and comparing it to $1/\beta$. The reaaon for this descrepancy is that ordinary least squares is not about fitting a line through points, but about *prediction* and thus assumes a specific role of the variables: *x* is "predictor", *y* is "response".

If your problem is actually about fitting a line through points, you should consider "orthogonal least squares", which is a symmetric approach and has (for straight lines) two equivalent solutions:

1. the right singular vector $\vec{v}_1$ corresponding to the largest singular
   value $s_1\geq\ldots\geq s_n$ in the singular value decomposition (SVD)
   $Q=USV^T$ of the matrix built from the centered data points
   $$Q^T = (\vec{q}_1,\ldots,\vec{q}_n) \quad\mbox{ with }\quad
   \vec{q}_i = \vec{x}_i - \vec{a}$$
2. the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $Q^TQ$. $Q^TQ$
   is identical to the scatter matrix, or $(n-1)$ times the covariance matrix
   of the data points $\vec{x}_1,\ldots,\vec{x}_n$. Thus, this vector is
   simply the principal component obtained from a principal component
   analysis (PCA)

Note that orthogonal least squares also yields a reasonable result when the points happen to fall on (or around) a vertical line.

Reference:

> H. Späth: "Orthogonal least squares fitting with linear manifolds."
> Numerische Mathematik 48 (1986), pp. 441–445.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder whether there's a way to prove that it is not a good estimator for $\frac{1}{\beta}$?